# Angular js app digest infinite error loop on startup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am new to Angular. I am building a new project using node, jade and angular. Trying to implement a catch all server route. When the index page loads up it goes into this loop that crashes the app. I have tried several different things to try to get it to work. Not sure what I am doing wrong!!

Node main routes

```
 module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
            bootstrappedAccount:req.user
        });
    });
    app.get('/partials/*',function(req,res){
        res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params[0]);
    });
}
```

Index.jade

```
 extends ../includes/layout.jade

block main.js-content
    .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
        .container
            .navbar-header
                a.navbar-brand(href='/') Template

            .navbar-collapse.collapse
                ul.nav.navbar-nav
                    li
                        a(href='/') home
                div(ng-include="'/partials/account/navbar-login'")
    section.content
        div(ng-view)

     footer.container.text-center
        p &copy; 2016 Company Name Corp International Ltd.
```

layout.jade (where angular is loaded. If I take out ng-app('app') from body the page loads. So I know its angular app thats causing issue.

```
doctype html

html
    head
        title Template
        link(href="/favicon.ico",rel="shortcut icon",type="image/x-icon")
        link(rel="stylesheet",href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet",href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet",href="/css/customsite.css")

    body(ng-app='app')
        include currentUser
        block main.js-content
        include scripts
```

app.js (Initalize Angular app)

```
  angular.module('app',['ngResource','ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/main/main', controller: 'mvMainCtrl'})
});
```

main.jade

```
.container
.jumbotron
    h1 The Startup Project
    p This appy.
.row
    .col-md-6
        div(ng-include="'/partials/main/featured-courses'")
    .col-md-6
        div(ng-include="'/partials/main/new-courses'")
```

Comment: I think if you are using  `app.get('*', functionction(req,res){});` every route will be redirected to same page ie `index` so get ride of that and check

Comment: I had faced a similar issue once. In my case it was because the `templateUrl`s which I had provided, pointed to files that did not exist. You should check your `templateUrl`, and maybe the paths in your `ng-include`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my app.js file in the templateUrl section. I was not passing in the string route value properly therefore it would go back and reload the server '/' page and load the client '/' continuously. I just changed the string to '/partials/?path=/main/main' this way my route for partials do not have to change. If you want to load without the partials route. PLEASE be sure that the path is correct on the templateUrl. If you are having issues more than likely its that route. Just play around with that until you figure it out. I even changed my to '/signup' just to be sure that the digest error stopped and I was on the right path to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to set this one up:

```
app.get('/partials/*',function(req,res){
    res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params[0]);
});
```

Angular should load the partials you include without you setting special routes on the server side.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this route does not even get hit before it crashes. Even if I left it in why would this be an issue?

Comment: Fair enough! Do you have a mvMainCtrl? Are there any console errors?